# what is the realtionship betweent DDD and Microservices

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

The microservice architecture is well known and will not be repeated here. When we create microservices, we need to create a microservice with high cohesion and low coupling. The bounded context in DDD perfectly matches the requirements of microservices, and the bounded context can be understood as a microservice process.

The above is to describe the similarities between the two from a more intuitive point of view.

After the system is complicated, we all need to use divide and conquer to disassemble the problem. There are generally two ways, the technical dimension and the business dimension. The technical dimension is similar to MVC, while the business dimension refers to dividing the system by business areas.

The microservice architecture emphasizes dividing and conquering from the business dimension to deal with system complexity, and DDD also focuses on the business perspective. If the goals (business dimensions) pursued by the two achieve the unity of the context, what are the connections and differences in specific practices?

Answer (score 1):

DDD is a strategy based on modeling your business using OOP, implementing business requirements directly within the model. DDD helps building software more **effective**, by allowing better mutual understanding between software programmers and business experts.

Microservices is a software architecture. It drives how to technically structure your software to achieve good execution performance, scalability, security and maintainability of a growing code base without expanding the technical debt. It helps building software more **efficient**.

Actually the two concepts are very orthogonal although both are needed for good software quality. You could, however, make a non DDD microservice, or a monolithic DDD application.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, when we think of distributed systems and microservices we think of DDD as well. Both approaches don't live alone, they are a complement of each other.

There are a lot of reasons why we segregate our applications in microservices, which may get for business or technical approach and we always use the DDD concepts to translate the business world for our tech world.